# sort struct not working

Tags: c, sorting, struct

Hello I'm trying to sort struct but for some reason it does not work so I'll be happy If you can help me fix the problem. Thanks.

(N = 6)

My sort-

```
for(i = 0; i < N-1; i++) 
{  
    for(j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
    {    
        if(basketball[i].points_number > basketball[i].points_number) 
        {     
            temp = basketball[i].points_number; 
            basketball[i] = basketball[j];   
            basketball[j].points_number = temp;   
        }
    }
}
```

My struct -

```
struct player
{
    char name[20]; 
    float height;
    float points_number; 
    int vest_number; 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
basketball[i] = basketball[i];
```

i.e., are overwriting the same entry with itself. I think, it should read

```
basketball[i] = basketball[j];  // Note the "j" on the right-hand side of the assignment
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have

```
if(basketball[i].points_number > basketball[i].points_number)
```

where you want (notice the `j`)

```
if(basketball[j].points_number > basketball[i].points_number)
```

Then, you have to swap the whole structure, not just the `points_number`structure, and so you'll have

```
struct player temp = basketball[i]; 
basketball[i] = basketball[j];   
basketball[j] = temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < N-1; i++) 
{  
    for(j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
    {    
        if(basketball[i].points_number > basketball[j].points_number) 
        {     
            temp = basketball[i]; 
            basketball[i] = basketball[j];   
            basketball[j] = temp;   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this line:

```
if(basketball[i].points_number > basketball[i].points_number)
```

Here you are comparing the same values as both ith elements are getting checked in basketball[i]. It should be:

```
if(basketball[i].points_number > basketball[j].points_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap structs of players, but you save in the temp variable only points. Should be

```
        struct player temp;
        temp = basketball[i]; 
        basketball[i] = basketball[j];   
        basketball[j] = temp;
```